# HOW to correctly connect to WCF service using bootstrap token

Tags: .net, wcf, wif

I cannot find what I`m doing wrong.

When I try to call service operation I get error:

The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

```
    using (Ref.SService_V1_0Client client = new Ref.SService_V1_0Client("RWS"))
{
    var request = new Ref.IVISRequestStructure();
    request.Header = new Ref.RequestHeaderStructure();


    client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
    ChannelFactoryOperations.ConfigureChannelFactory(client.ChannelFactory);
    ChannelFactoryOperations.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken<Ref.ISService_V1_0>(client.ChannelFactory, ((Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)(Page.User.Identity)).BootstrapToken);
    client.StartTransaction("string argument");
}
```

Configuration in web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
      <binding name="ws2007FederationUserName" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" negotiateServiceCredential="true">
            <issuer address="adress/STS/Issue.svc/trust/13/issuedtokenmixedsymmetricbasic256" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="issuedtokenmixedsymmetricbasic256"/>
          </message>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="another_address/servicename.svc/ws2007Federation"
      binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws2007FederationUserName"
      contract="Ref.ISService_V1_0" name="RWS" />
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the return value of the CreateChannelWithIssuedToken call to invoke the service instead of using the client variable. See the [CreateChannel code in this sample for how CreateChannelWithIssuedToken  is used.](http://blogs.southworks.net/mwoloski/2008/12/14/managing-the-lifecycle-of-security-tokens-geneva-sts-wcf/) It would look like this:

```
var serviceClient = ChannelFactoryOperations.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken<Ref.ISService_V1_0>(client.ChannelFactory, ((Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)(Page.User.Identity)).BootstrapToken);
serviceClient.StartTransaction("string argument");
```